# Inject a code into a random place after a paragraph using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to know how can I use HtmlAgilityPack to inject a certain pre-defined HTML content (e.g. an ad) into a random place in an HTML article after closing paragraph and make it only once?

The article might have several paragraphs. The injected code should choose a random paragraph and put the code after it.

This is my code so far:

```
 public string InjectAHtmlRandomallyIntoArticle(string originalArticleHtmlCode,
                                                string HtmlToInject)
 {
     HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
     doc.LoadHtml(input);
     HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection pars = 
          new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection(doc.DocumentNode.ParentNode);
     pars = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");


    foreach(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode par in pars)
    {

    }
}
```

Don't know where yo continue from there.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. You should try an implementation and come back with a more specific question when you come unstuck.

Comment: @spender I've added the code and where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't need crypto-level randomness so the good old Random will suffice.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
//Next returns a value smaller than it's argument
pars[rnd.Next(par.Length)].Append(your add);
```

Comment: HtmlNode doesn't have a function called "Append"

Comment: Well I don't know html-agility-pack, I figured your question was more about the random part. Try AppendChild then.